# NewDocumentCommand with argument specifiers stored in macro

Tags: macros, xparse

I am trying to write some macros that in turn automatically generate other macros, depending on options etc.

I wonder, if it's possible to use `\NewDocumentCommand{\somename}{\standardargs}`, i.e. the argument list itself is 'hidden' in a macro.

Here is a non-working, short example (the non-necessary overhead is removed, of course)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\standardargs}{O{}+m}

\NewDocumentCommand{\somecmd}{\standardargs}{%
  % Do something more or less useful
  My args: #2
}


\begin{document}
\somecmd{Hello World}
\end{document}
```

The error message is

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "xparse/unknown-argument-type"
! 
! Unknown argument type '\standardargs' replaced by 'm'.
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.10 }
```

Some notes

- I am pretty sure, this is some expansion problem
- I **am** aware that I might have to use a more sophisticated approach to maintain the `{}` brackets as optional value default specifiers for `\NewDocumentCommand`.
- The usage/usability of such a standard argument list might be doubtful, I would agree with that.

Comment: As I wrote already in my question and the comments by egreg and Joseph Wright point to the same direction: It's possible, but not advisable to use this strategy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, expand the macro before `\NewDocumentCommand` tries to grab the second (macro definition) argument:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\standardargs}{O{}+m}

\expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\expandafter\somecmd\expandafter{\standardargs}{%
  % Do something more or less useful
  My args: #2
}


\begin{document}
\somecmd{Hello World}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Werner, I could swear, I had such statements. Even in conjunction with the fact, that this should be even inside, defining the the macro actually, i.e. `\expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname SomeCommand#1\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\standardargs}`, but perhaps I was missing one `\expandafter` at the right position

Comment: I will have a look tomorrow, it's late here already

Answer (score 6):

l3 allows you to avoid `\expandafter`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\standardargs}{O{}+m}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\MyNewDocumentCommand{\exp_args:NNo\NewDocumentCommand}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\MyNewDocumentCommand{\somecmd}{\standardargs}{%
  % Do something more or less useful
  My args: #2
}


\begin{document}
\somecmd{Hello World}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, David. I think, I should switch to `expl3` for my project anyway.

Answer (score 6):

It is exactly an expansion problem. Here's the definition of `\NewDocumentCommand`:

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \NewDocumentCommand #1#2#3
  {
    \cs_if_exist:NTF #1
      {
        \__msg_kernel_error:nnx { xparse } { command-already-defined }
          { \token_to_str:N #1 }
      }
      { \__xparse_declare_cmd:Nnn #1 {#2} {#3} }
  }
```

It would be very easy to define a variation that accepts an argument to be expanded, if `\__xparse_declare_cmd:Nnn` was among the public functions, but it isn't. Without going against the programming conventions you could do it yourself:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \hupfer_newdocumentcommand:Nnn \NewDocumentCommand
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \hupfer_newdocumentcommand:Nnn { No }
\NewDocumentCommand\NewDocumentCommandExp{mmm}
 {
  \hupfer_newdocumentcommand:Non #1 { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

and then your syntax

```
\NewDocumentCommandExp{\somecmd}{\standardargs}{%
  % Do something more or less useful
  My args: #2
}
```

would work. What this can be useful for, I really don't know.

Comment: Of course, this is entirely against the spirit of `xparse`: the point is that the interfaces should be documented as part of the code itself.

Comment: @JosephWright Agreed: this is a wrong approach to `xparse`. On the other hand, I can vaguely see applications for `\NewNamedDocumentCommand` that gets as its first argument a command name ( `c` style, to be clearer) in case one has to build a series of commands from some variable data.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, it's an abuse of the benefits of `xparse`. I will use another strategy for the relevant code. Thanks for your explicit and quick answer!